# Typo3 Condition => Symfony-Expression Language: IP in List

Tags: symfony, typo3

What's the right symfony-expression-syntax for the "in List" typo3 conditions? (For Example IP or Language described here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/8.7/en-us/Conditions/Reference/Index.html

This is the condition with a inList-constante I like to migrate:

```
[IP = {$mainTemplate.IPList}]
  someTyposcript
[end]
```

Comment: [ip("172.18.*")] should do so. https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Conditions/#ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the symfony syntax is  `[ip("<data>"]` and for `data` the documentation states: `Value or Constraint, Wildcard or RegExp possible`.

Depending on the IPs you want to cover you have some options:
as you asked specific for `in List` I assume you have multiple IPs:

- wildcards: like 10.123.98.*
- RegExp: 10.123.98.10|10.123.98.40|10.234.12.14

as you see, you might need to change your IP list if it consits of a comma separated list to a pipe(`|`) separated list

Comment: Thank you very much! RegExp with comma to pipe is the solution. The following fact is **VERY BAD** : I can't use the new $mainTemplate.pipeIPList in Typoscript: `if.isInList = {$mainTemplate.pipeIPList}` => So I have to create two IP-Lists with the same IPs 1. $mainTemplate.pipeIPList 2. $mainTemplate.commaIPList
**Is there a solution to avoid this?**

Comment: maybe you could modify the value in typoscript. use a `.stdWrap.replacement` on the value.otherwise a userfunc to use in the condition with e reverse-replacement comes to mind.

Comment: maybe you can move the typoscript which depends on the IP into the condition, so you don't need the `.stdWrap.if`

Comment: Yes, with ".stdWrap.replacement" it should be possible. Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: I found out that the following RegExp Syntax is NOT working: ` [ip("10.123.98.10|127.0.0.*")]`
but the following with **"Old Comma Style" is working**: ` [ip("10.123.98.10,127.0.0.*")]`
Here is a example for comma-list at the point "loginUser" : [link](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Conditions/Index.html) I can not find a example for RegExp here!